# Octoparse Xpath or iframe Problem extracting

Tags: xpath, iframe

I am trying to extract the prices of some products in Mercado Libre website.

The problem is that sometimes it has discounts, and then it doesn't extract the text.

I leave one link with discount and one without. I want octoparse to extract the price in both situations.

How can I do it?

LINKS:
https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-666847965-funda-protector-iphone-7-8-se-2020-supcase-ubstyle-negro-_JM?quantity=1#position=1&type=item&tracking_id=9e0a5e4a-891d-4b89-add3-7aca91d6969a

https://articulo.mercadolibre.com.mx/MLM-721688631-protector-funda-case-rudo-iphone-6-7-8-x-xs-xr-xs-max-11-pro-_JM?quantity=1#searchVariation=43860021612&position=8&type=pad&tracking_id=9e0a5e4a-891d-4b89-add3-7aca91d6969a&is_advertising=true&ad_domain=VQCATCORE_LST&ad_position=8&ad_click_id=YTY0MWNiMWQtMDFmNi00ZGJmLThjZjMtYWM3YWQyZTc3OWNl

Answer (score 0):

I don't know well Octoparse, but if you can specify XPath manually then you can go with :

```
(//fieldset[contains(@class,"item-price")]//@content)[last()]
```

This will select exact price (with decimals) of the items. The value is taken from the attribute of the holding `span` element. So in your case :

`254.62` and `250.0` will be extracted.

Alternative ways :

A) :

```
string(//fieldset[contains(@class,"item-price")]//span[@class="price-tag"])
```

Output :

`$ 254 . 62` and  `$ 250`

B) :

```
(//fieldset[contains(@class,"item-price")]//span[@class="price-tag-fraction"]/text())[last()]
```

Output :

`254` and `250`